# How do I loop through two lists of lists and avoid duplicate combinations for values at specific positions?

Tags: python, list, loops, duplicates, combinations

I would like to loop through two lists of lists and avoid duplicate combinations of values between positions 1 and 2 of each list.

```
a = [[2007, 206, 205, 8], [2007, 206, 208, 9]]
b = [[2007, 205, 206, 8], [2007, 207, 210, 10]]
```

In this case for a[0], positions 1 and 2 would be 206 and 205 respectively, and for b[0], positions 1 and 2 would be 205 and 206. a[0] and b[0] derive from the same data set, but are structured differently. However, b[0] would be a duplicate of a[0] based on the combination. How do I avoid having this combination-based duplicate?

Thank you.

Comment: Python has a `set` data structure that you might find useful.

Comment: What do you want to happen to `b[0]` since it is a "duplicate"?

Comment: What do you want to do to "avoid" duplicates?  Create a new list c with all the non-duplicate records from a and b?  Delete records from a or from b?  Deduplicate across all the lists in a and b, or just duplicates between corresponding positions?

Comment: i want to remove b[0] and any other duplicates in the lists of lists combinations and append to a final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a result of something like:

```
c = [[2007, 206, 205, 8], [2007, 206, 208, 9], [2007, 207, 210, 10]]
```

That should be easy enough:

```
a = [[2007, 206, 205, 8], [2007, 206, 208, 9]]
b = [[2007, 205, 206, 8], [2007, 207, 210, 10]]
from itertools import chain
seen = set()
c = []
for lst in chain(a,b):
    one_two = tuple(lst[:1] + sorted(lst[1:-1]) + lst[-1:])
    if one_two not in seen:
       seen.add(one_two)
       c.append(lst)
```

Comment: You keep fixing problems right before I comment on them. :^)  But I think you need to use all four values in the key; otherwise you can't distinguish between 4-tuples with different starts and ends but the same middle numbers.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I know.  as I understood it, that was the desired behavior (otherwise, what's the special significance of the middle two?).  Are you proposing something like:  `tuple([lst[0]]+sorted(lst[1:3])+lst[3])`?

Comment: Hmm.  I thought that it was simply that the middle two weren't in a canonical order.  Right now, if you see [2012, 205, 206, 8] and then [2007, 205, 206, 9], the latter would be suppressed.  Edit: yeah, that was exactly my thought.

Comment: @DSM -- why?  I don't think this would suppress the latter (with my most recent edit) since `lst[3]` is preserved in the "key".

Comment: When I made the comment, before the "Edit:" there was no `lst[3]`. :^) +1 now, I think this removes "duplicates" in the sense the OP has given.

Comment: @hylaeus -- I edited one more time.  I like the symmetry with the slicing to get the first and last elements of the list.  It's more-or-less cosmetic, but ... I like it better

Comment: @DSM -- I decided that I like `tuple(lst[:1] + sorted(lst[1:-1]) + lst[-1:])` slightly more for cosmetic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_a = [sorted(x) for x in a]
filtered_b = filter(lambda x: sorted(x) not in sorted_a, b)
```

Comment: basically same combinations would be identical after sorting. you can do that with whole sub-list or part of it.